# Passing data to into a query, not updating

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a simple program for saving values each day along with a timestamp

[image: Firebase]

Once saved I want to choose a date an for my recycler view to show all value associated with it

Is there anyway to get passDate to update every time the button is pressed?

I realise this is probably a very simple fix but ive got myself in a loop.

I have tried taking the Query out of the onCreate but ran into trouble, and I cannot take the adapter out of the oncreate without running into major issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` runs asynchronously, so that picking a date doesn't block the rest of the app. This means that the date the user selected is only available within `onDateSet`. All code that requires the date must be within `onDateSet` or called from there.

So the simplest solution is to move all the code that depends on the date into `onDateSet`:

```
mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        String yearAsString = Integer.toString(year);
        String monthAsString = Integer.toString(month);
        String dayAsString = Integer.toString(day);
        if (day <= 9 & month <= 9) {
            String date = "0" + dayAsString + "-" + "0" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        } else if (day <= 9 & month > 9) {
            String date = "0" + dayAsString + "-" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        } else if (month <= 9) {
            String date = dayAsString + "-" + "0" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        } else {
            String date = dayAsString + "-" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }

        String passDate = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();

        Log.i(TAG, "PassDate = " + passDate);

        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(passDate);
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Records>().setQuery(query, Records.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Records, RecordsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecordsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Records model) {
                holder.t1.setText(model.getTimestamp());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecordsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_records_view, viewGroup, false);

                return new RecordsViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
};
```

You can also make your view class implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`, to reduce the indentation a bit:

```
public class SavedFeedRecords extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
```

That then means that `onDateSet` becomes a regular method on `SavedFeedRecords`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_feed_records);
    mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("feedRecords");


    findViewById(R.id.tvDate).setOnClickListener(displayDate);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(viewRecords);
};

public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    month = month + 1;
    String yearAsString = Integer.toString(year);
    String monthAsString = Integer.toString(month);
    String dayAsString = Integer.toString(day);
    if (day <= 9 & month <= 9) {
        String date = "0" + dayAsString + "-" + "0" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
        mDisplayDate.setText(date);
    } else if (day <= 9 & month > 9) {
        String date = "0" + dayAsString + "-" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
        mDisplayDate.setText(date);
    } else if (month <= 9) {
        String date = dayAsString + "-" + "0" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
        mDisplayDate.setText(date);
    } else {
        String date = dayAsString + "-" + monthAsString + "-" + yearAsString;
        mDisplayDate.setText(date);
    }
    String passDate = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();

    Log.i(TAG, "PassDate = " + passDate);

    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(passDate);
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Records>().setQuery(query, Records.class).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Records, RecordsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecordsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Records model) {
            holder.t1.setText(model.getTimestamp());

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecordsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_records_view, viewGroup, false);

            return new RecordsViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Works a charm, All that time and I just have to copy and paste the code 2 semi colons up lol, that's coding for you, thanks so much